# Virucides - Herbal and otherwise, for HHV6 type virus or any inner-cell virus

Tags: human-biology, biochemistry, virology

Does anyone know where I can find a reliable list of virucides (not anti-virus) that can be used by humans? This virucide must be able to affect viruses that are already inside the cells. St John's Wort is considered a virucide along with it's other properties, for example.